# User to specify directory path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to give my users an option to select a directory path on their local machine (not select an actual file).

This is so they can save xml files into a directory on their hard drive.  When user selects the directory I want to pass that path to my code which then loads data from the xml files into my database.

I know I can get the users to select a file:

```
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

But this is not what I want, I want them to just select the directory.

Can someone advise if this is easily done in an MVC application.

Comment: So far what you asking is not possible. Can you please clarify how do you plan to "which then loads data from the xml files" assuming path is on user's machine and you somehow magically try to read files from server side code on machine that have no access to user's machine... Maybe I'm missing whole point of question - consider clarifying on what machine (user's or server) each operation happens.

Answer (score 0):

A web application cannot directly write to a user's computer. The best you can do is provide a downloadable link and the user needs to do a **SAVE AS** from the browser.

In your case, forget about the directory path and just give a link/button on your web page to get the XML files.

**On click**, generate the XML file from the Database and use the following snippet for the user to get a download prompt.

```
// code on the click of the button/link

FileInfo file = new FileInfo(tempFilePathOnServer);

Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.Name + "\"");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
Response.Flush();
Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
Response.End();
```